# I have a email subscription form and i want to add a url to that subscription button without losing function of email subscription in html

Tags: html

I have a email subscription form and i want to add a url to that subscription button without losing function of email subscription in html
html code of button

Comment: where is your code ? what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your question is specifically, or how your code looks like.

Assuming your code has a `<button>` in it, you would wrap the `<button>` in a `<a href>`.

For example:

```
<body>
    <a href="#">    <!--Replace # with your link-->
        <button>    <!--Your button-->
        </button>
    </a>
</body>
```

This applies to most other objects (images for example).

Hope that helps!